# Why won't my new water valves turn on?

Tags: bathroom, sink, valve

Alright I just replaced my bathroom sink and faucet had some problems but managed through.  Turned my water back on and the went back to the bathroom sink to turn the valves on but they won't turn.  The valves are brand new quarter turn Sharkbite stop valves.  What could I have done wrong?  Both valves are in exactly the same state, they just won't turn.

Comment: Did they turn before you connected them? How much force have you tried with?

Comment: sounds silly, but are you turning them in the right direction?

Comment: Thought they turned before hand I could be wrong though.

Comment: Tried a fair amount of force they don't budge not even a little.  I tried both directions to turn but just in case but I'm following the arrows so I should be turning the right way.

Comment: A picture of the valves might help.  They are not the locking type are they?  Some quarter turn valves have a locking mechanism that holds them in the off position, I'm not sure if any SharkBite valves have this but it's worth a look.

Comment: Sometimes ball valves are "sticky" from the manufacturer, and they take a bit of extra effort to turn them the first few times. It's always a good idea to turn them on and off a few times before installing them.

Comment: I know these are sharkbites, but did you happen to do any soldering anywhere else near by? if so it might be possible that you melted the plastic ball in the valve

Comment: Try opening and closing the valves with the water turned off.  You have the mains pressure pushing on one side of the valve, and that combined with new-valve stickiness, might be enough to make it hard to turn.

Comment: Alright took off work early to take care of this before my wife gets home.  Turned the water off, let the pipes drain through sink in basement, put in wrench on the valve to hold it, grabbed the handle with vise grips and turned.  It took a fair amount of effort but it gave way and opened.  I was afraid that turning that hard would ruin it.  Now it turns back and forth easy and smooth.  Thanks for the help, never new they could be so "sticky".

Comment: @Rick might I suggest compiling the excellent advice you've gotten here into a single answer of your own question?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above discussion and my own experience:

Turn the water off and twist hard.  New ball valves can be sticky, and the house water pressure behind the valve could be making that situation worse.

Apparently this worked for the original poster.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and after some playing around I did the following. The tap had a little screw that holds the cover handle thingie that you grip and turn. I undid the screw, took off the handle thingie and then turned the faucet off and on a few times with a wrench on the brass stick. It was just stuck turning the first time. I couldn't get enough torque using the handle thingie. Once I had turned it off and on a few times with a wrench, it was fine and I could then put the cover thingie back on and turn it easily.

Answer (score 0):

One big reason this happens is that most people open the valve all the way open. When this is done, it will cause the shutoff to be stick and possibly leak later in it's life. Always open the value all the way and then turn it back (off) a 1/6 or 1/4 turn so it's not "locked" in the open position.

This pertains to these types of values (if this images showup)

[Value Type One](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=water%20shutoff%20valve%20images&hl=en&safe=strict&sa=X&noj=1&biw=1467&bih=644&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=THAzwuqpXCjIMM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.askmehelpdesk.com/plumbing/shut-off-valve-not-working-32414-3.html&docid=rOxunWuwJ2KPoM&imgurl=http://www.askmehelpdesk.com/attachments/plumbing/1453d1159049572-shut-off-valve-not-working-185_8554.jpg&w=750&h=563&ei=xe3xT9-YD4X8qwH4t_H2AQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=430&vpy=312&dur=510&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=130&ty=221&sig=102098225356640390101&page=1&tbnh=143&tbnw=190&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:10,s:0,i:106)
[Value Type Two](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=water%20shutoff%20valve%20images&hl=en&safe=strict&sa=X&noj=1&biw=1467&bih=644&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=NCgEgMePJ8_R6M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Plumbing/Plumbing-Repair/fixing-a-water-shutoff-valve-leak/View-All&docid=gpKexjl8XeJ5yM&imgurl=http://hostedmedia.reimanpub.com/TFH/Projects/FH02OCT_WAVALE_01.JPG&w=600&h=600&ei=xe3xT9-YD4X8qwH4t_H2AQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=915&vpy=139&dur=435&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=60&ty=246&sig=102098225356640390101&page=1&tbnh=148&tbnw=144&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:0,i:90)

Comment: The OP mentioned "new quarter turn" valve which means its a ball valve and not a gate valve.  Ball valves do not have this problem which is a benefit to using them.

Answer (score 0):

The 1/4 turn valves from my experience are often affected by water pressure and shutting of the main, and draining the lines a bit will often help. Take your time with these valves when they are mated to PEX as too much force could damage nearby fittings.